# Firebase Firestore check data is in ArrayList

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make query like below.

If field value is in arrayList, get that documents!

But, I can't find how to do like that..

```
fireStore.collection("UsedItems").orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
    if(firebaseFirestoreException != null) { return@addSnapshotListener }
    itemList.clear()

    for(snapshot in querySnapshot!!.documents) {
        val item = snapshot?.toObject(DataItem::class.java)
        if(item!!.location in closeLocationList && item.category !in App.preference.notSelectedCategory) {
            itemList.add(item)
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

In this code, `closeLocationList` and `App.preference.notSelectedCategory` are ArrayList.

There are two conditions, but I want to get specified documents that filtered on network.

Not call all documents and filtering on Kotlin code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an [`IN` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any), which would look something like this:

```
fireStore.collection("UsedItems")
 .orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
 .whereIn("location", closeLocationList)
 .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->

    if(firebaseFirestoreException != null) { return@addSnapshotListener }
    itemList.clear()

    for(snapshot in querySnapshot!!.documents) {
        val item = snapshot?.toObject(DataItem::class.java)
        if (item.category !in App.preference.notSelectedCategory) {
            itemList.add(item)
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

A few things to note here:

- This only works for up to 10 locations. If you need to filter by more locations, you'll need to do one query for each 10 locations, and merge the results for thos queries in your Kotlin code.
- You'll need to filter the category in your Kotlin code, because Firestore queries cannot do a `not equals` type query on the server.